# Сложение (прикрепление) числа к букве C++

Tags: c++

Как можно число `n = 10`
Сложить с буквами `aa` (это пример)? Чтобы в конце получился вывод `aa10`

Comment: `string s = "aa"s+to_string(10);`

Comment: просто:  cout << "aa" << 10;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В С++ - для `string` - можно использовать простой `+`:

```
string a = "aa";
int n = 10;
string res = aa + to_string(n);
```

В C - использовать `sprintf` или ее безопасные аналоги:

```
char res[20];
sprintf(res,"%s%d","aa",10);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::ostringstream stream;
// воодите что хотите
stream << "aa" << 15 << 0.4 << "stream";
cout << stream.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
//...
int n=10;
string s="aa"+to_string(n);
```